# почему функция find  не хочет искать в строке

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string test ;
string test1 = "asdsd" ;
char forst[10000] ;
   int setck[10000] ;
   string vlck [100] ;

int readsom1(char flname[20],char* mass,string name)
{   ifstream in1;
   in1.open(flname);
   string lines;

      {
        string buff;
        while( !in1.eof())
        {
            getline(in1, buff);
            lines += buff + '\n';
        }
        in1.close();
         cout<<"reading the" <<" " <<(name) <<" file was successfully"<<endl ;
         cout <<"-----------------------------------------"<<endl ;
         strcpy(mass, lines.c_str());

    } ;
      cout <<"---------------------------------------------"<<endl;
return 0 ;

}
int readsom(char flname[20],string str,string name)
{    ifstream in ;
      in.open(flname);
      string lines;
 if (!in.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Error open file." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
     {
        string buff;
        while( !in.eof())
        {
            getline(in,buff);
            str += buff + '\n';
        }
        test = str ;
        //strcpy(forst, lines.c_str());

        in.close();

    } ;

      return 0 ;
in.close();

       } ;
int find (string whatf,int i )
{string str ;
readsom ("output.txt",test,test1);
cout << str ;
int pos ;
string str1 = test;
pos = test.find(whatf);
//cout << pos << endl << endl ;
setck[i]=pos ;
return 0;
};

int findeol ( int i , int start )
{

std::string::size_type pos = forst.find("typed");
if(pos!=string::npos)
{
std::string new_mod_s(forst.substr(pos));
std::cout<<new_mod_s<<std::endl;
}
  return 0;
}

char buffer [9999999];
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    ofstream f("output.txt");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
stream.connect("auth.mail.ru","http");
stream << "POST /cgi-bin/auth HTTP/1.1\r\n";
stream << "Host: e.mail.ru\r\n";
stream << "Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1\r\n";
stream << "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
stream << "Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n";
stream << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n";
stream << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
stream << "Referer: http://mail.ru/ \r\n";
stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
//stream << "Cookie: p=hVIDAE7rZAAA; i=AQB1z95PAQATAAgNBBAAARYnARgnARknAQ==; c=aYABUAEAAF5jAAAyAAAAAwAU; t=obLD1AAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAABAAAAAAIAAAAfAAgFywcA; gmt=4; Mpop=1339594240:517c02645e466e72190502190f1d00041c050b0b4966535c465d06040d010816000f03165e5d5f010205041658505d5b174345:gen1321@mail.ru:; b=rzwOAEAsHwQAXqYsWAvWgMUgA2gNDVxyNFDrxkBmygJzUAz/U2EEAAAxRhXGvXEJGVwi9LaGwOIcysDD7aWIq/gyxDNiGaMbtARexFSGGYYuAQAA; VID=3XcI090GMmX0; mrcu=A5564FFFF65F1A8CA655831E545Fpage=&post=&login_from=&lang=&Login=gen1321&Domain=mail.ru&Password=XXXX&level=0/r/n";
std::string content = "page=&post=&login_from=&lang=&Login=gen1321&Domain=mail.ru&Password=xxxx&level=0";
stream << "Content-Length: " <<content.length() << "\r\n";
stream << "\r\n";

         stream << content;

           stream.flush();
        f << stream.rdbuf();
        f.close();
stream.close ();

 find("Set-Cookie: Mpop=",1);
find("Set-Cookie: t=",2);
find("Set-Cookie: mrcu=",3);

cout<<setck[1]<<endl << setck[2]<<endl<<setck[3] << endl;
   readsom1("output.txt",forst,"sada");

   cout << forst ;

findeol (1,setck[1]);
findeol (2,setck[2]);
findeol (3,setck[3]);

stream.connect("e.mail.ru","http");
stream << "GET http://e.mail.ru/cgi-bin/msglist HTTP/1.1\r\n";
stream << "Host: e.mail.ru\r\n";
stream << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
stream << "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n";
stream << "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11\r\n";
stream << "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
stream << "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n";
stream << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";
stream << "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n";

stream.flush();

   stream.close ();
   f<< stream.rdbuf();
   f.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Ошибки следующие 
Error error C2228: left of '.find' must have class/struct/union

error C2228: left of '.substr' must have class/struct/union

И не моглибы вы подсказать как улучшить мой быдлокод?)

Comment: Ошибка на какой строчке?

Answer (score 3):

Вы применяете методы `find` и `substr` к переменной `forst`, а это имя не объекта типа `string`, а массива `char`.